# Firebase security rules authentication in react native

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

My user is authenticating using react native and it works great but now Google keeps telling that my security rules are not safe. This is what I have now:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

This is my current database structure. Can anyone help me with how I can improve the security of my app please? Thanks in advance

[image]

[image]

I already followed all the tutorials online but still couldn't find a solution

Comment: I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-fix-firestore-error-permission-denied-missing-or-insufficient-permissions-777d591f404) will also help.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone who is signed into Firebase can access any and all data in the database. That means that any of your users can read, overwrite, and delete the data of all your other users. While this may be precisely what you want, it seems unlikely.

More likely you only want the users to be able to read/write their own user profile. You'd do that with rules like those on the documentation on [owner-only access](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#content-owner_only_access).

Similarly, you'll probably want to restrict access to the blocks, for example to only allow the creator to modify them.